# MYSQL SELECT rows not in query

Tags: mysql, user-agent, bots, exists

I have a statistics database for people who have visited. This table contains ID, timestamp IPv4, IPv6, User Agent and REQUEST_URI. I get false numbers by running something like

`SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT IPv4) AS 'Uniques', COUNT(*) AS 'Total' FROM statistics`

So I need to filter out the bots from humans. My approach is this:

`SELECT ID FROM statistics WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT ID FROM statistics WHERE useragent NOT LIKE '%bot%')`

This should select all rows from statistics which are not present in the query which searches for non-bots. I think the query looks reasonable so why isn't it working?

And there is a reason I want to do it this way instead of

`SELECT ID FROM statistics WHERE useragent LIKE '%bot%'`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a bit confused, but maybe you want to do:

```
SELECT ID FROM statistics 
WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM statistics WHERE useragent NOT LIKE '%bot%')
```

Comment: NOT EXISTS differs from NOT IN. For more information look at [MSDN EXISTS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/ms188336.aspx) (you're using MYSQL and not MS SQL Server, but the meaning of these keywords doesn't differ).